# Checking for corrupt war file after mvn install

Tags: java, maven-2, jar, war

Is there a maven command that will verify that a WAR file is valid and not corrupt?  Or is there some other program or technique to validate zip files? I'm on Ubuntu 9.10, so a linux solution is preferred.

On occasion, I end up with a corrupt WAR file after doing `mvn clean` and `mvn install` on my project. If I extract the WAR file to my hard drive, an error occurs and the file doesn't get extracted.  I believe this happens when my system is in a low-memory condition, because this tends to happen only when lots of memory is in use. After rebooting, doing a `mvn install` always gives a valid WAR file.

Because this happens infrequently, I don't typically test the file by uncompressing it. I transfer the 50MB war file to my server and then restart Jetty with it as the root webapp. But when the file is corrupt, I get a `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type` error.

So I'm looking for a quick way to validate the file as soon as mvn install is completed. Is there a maven command to do this? Any other ideas?

Comment: @krosenvold: Yes, I'm running 64-bit. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 3):

Your corruption could be due to [PLXCOMP-149](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/PLXCOMP-149). If you supress the included version of plexus-io that comes with the war plugin and replace it with the newly released 1.0, your problems just might go away.

I know I'm not answering your question, but I might solve your problem. Add a dependency to

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
<artifactId>plexus-io</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

To your war plugin's [plugin](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins) section.

Comment: And do tell me if it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) for this. I'd consider implementing an integration test (start war in a servlet container and do a some smoke test) as well.

Comment: I'll take a look at the dependency plugin. Thanks for the suggestion! I will eventually get integration tests going too, just not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to add a step which invokes the `antrun` plugin to do an `<unzip>` of the output WAR to a temporary file.